# Angular2 - one store, multiple component, different API call

Tags: angular, components, rxjs, store

Let's say I've a parent component, `HomeComponent`, with multiple nested component, `TeamsStandingComponent`.
`TeamsStandingComponent` must show data collected from an API call, using a common but private store, `TeamsStandingStore`.

Now I'll show you my code.

`HomeComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: '../templates/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(
  ) {}
}
```

And this is the `HomeComponent` template:

```
<div class="top-three-standings__wrapper">
  <teams-standing #standing1 [leagueId]="426"></teams-standing>
  <teams-standing #standing2 [leagueId]="439"></teams-standing>
</div>
```

This is the `TeamsStandingComponent`:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef,
  ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { TeamsStandingStore } from '../stores/teams-standing';
import { HttpClient } from '../services/http-client'; // you can ignore this

@Component({
  selector: 'teams-standing',
  providers: [HttpClient], // you can ignore this
  templateUrl: '../templates/teams-standing.html'
})
export class TeamsStandingComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() private teams: Object;
  @Input() private leagueId: string;
  private teamsStandingStore: TeamsStandingStore;

  constructor(
    private TeamsStandingStore: TeamsStandingStore,
    private ngzone: NgZone,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    console.clear();
    this.teamsStandingStore = TeamsStandingStore;
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular( () => {

      this.teamsStandingStore.standings
        .subscribe( (data) => {
          this.teams = data;
          this.cdref.detectChanges();
        } );
    });

    this.http.get(`competitions/` + this.leagueId + `/leagueTable`)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => this.teamsStandingStore.showStandings(data.json()),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

And this is the `TeamsStandingComponent` template:

```
<div class="teams-standing__table">
  <h2>{{leagueId}} - {{teams?._links?.competition?.href}}</h2>
  <h3>{{teams?.leagueCaption}}</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let team of teams?.standing">
    {{team.teamName}}
    {{team.crestURI}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally this is the `TeamStandingStore`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }  from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TeamsStandingStore {

  private standings: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  private showStands: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.showStands
      .subscribe(this.standings);
  }

  public showStandings(standings) {
    this.showStands.next(standings);
  }

}
```

My issue is that those nested component, `TeamsStandingComponent`, show the same data, even if **every** component calls a different endpoint - *as you can see* - and has a different response.

PS: I'm using @angular v.2.4.9 and rxjs v.5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all the nested components are getting the same value because they are all using the same instance of the `TeamStandingStore`.

You do not show your module where you are providing your `TeamStandingStore`, but my guess your providing it as the module level.  This means every component is getting the same instance of the Store and thus all subscribing to the same `standings` observable.

What you may want to do in this case is provide the Store at the component level instead of at the module level so each `TeamStandingComponent` has it's own instance.  You would do this by providing the `TeamStandingStore` in the component decorator like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'teams-standing',
  providers: [HttpClient, TeamStandingStore], // <- insert TeamStandingStore here
  templateUrl: '../templates/teams-standing.html'
})
export class TeamsStandingComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() private teams: Object;
  @Input() private leagueId: string;
  private teamsStandingStore: TeamsStandingStore;

  constructor(
    private TeamsStandingStore: TeamsStandingStore,
    private ngzone: NgZone,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    console.clear();
    this.teamsStandingStore = TeamsStandingStore;
  }
```

Comment: yes, I forgot to copy the NgModule code here. Of course I expose `TeamStandingStore` there. And yes, your solution works like a charm, I've added `TeamStandingStore` in `TeamsStandingComponent ` providers array. Thank you very much!